# Can't find Debian Squeeze 32 bit

Tags: debian, distributions

I can't find where to download Debian 6.0.5 Squeeze 32 bit. Are CD images of old distributions available at all? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the [FAQ](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#old), you can find some old CD images in [the CD image archive](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/). You’ll find `i386` images of Debian 6.0.5 [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/6.0.5/i386/), but only as [Jigdo templates](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#why-jigdo). You’ll have to use the templates along with the `jigdo` tool to reconstruct the images locally.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, download: https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/6.0.5-live/i386/usb-hdd/debian-live-6.0.5-i386-gnome-desktop.img and dd it to a USB drive and boot from that.

You could also plug the USB into another system and expand the partition to use the whole drive, or create a new partition in the free space and make a persistent home directory there.

- Copy your current home over then change the fstab entry to point to the new home location and make the entry so mounts it with read and write ability.

So, to answer your question if you dig through the archives, you can find what you need or you can at least find something you can make work.

Answer (score 0):

Once you downloaded the ISO, you'll want to have access to the repository.

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/ squeeze main contrib non-free
```